# Zoom function for canvas elements with only using position and size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I need help with a canvas problem.

I have some images with a given position and size and I want to make a function for zooming them based on a point on canvas.

I want to do it without any canvas functions like scale or translate. I just the function to change the images position and size to make it work.

Here is a code example missing only the part I need:

```js
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const canvasW = canvas.width;
        const canvasH = canvas.height;

        //These will be images, but the idea is the same.
        var rects = [
            {
                originalX:10,
                x:10,
                originalY:10,
                y:10,
                originalW:25,
                w:25,
                originalH:25,
                h:25,
                color:'blue'
            },
            {
                originalX:90,
                x:90,
                originalY:40,
                y:40,
                originalW:65,
                w:65,
                originalH:35,
                h:35,
                color:'red'
            },
            {
                originalX:80,
                x:80,
                originalY:120,
                y:120,
                originalW:30,
                w:30,
                originalH:30,
                h:30,
                color:'pink'
            },
            {
                originalX:180,
                x:180,
                originalY:190,
                y:190,
                originalW:45,
                w:45,
                originalH:35,
                h:35,
                color:'green'
            }
        ];


        //Zoom Data:
        var zoomData = {
            x:150, //The center of the zoom function. (The canvas center in this case)
            y:150, // <-->
            level: 1, //Zoom level: 1 means no change, >1 means zoom content, <1 means unzoom content.
            direction: 1 //Zoom direction: 1 means increasing, -1 decreasing.
        };



        function draw(){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);

            //Draw some background.
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);

            //Draw each rectangle (image).
            for(var rect of rects){
                ctx.fillStyle = rect.color;
                ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
            }

            //Draw the zoom center point.
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            ctx.fillRect(zoomData.x - 5/2, zoomData.y - 5/2, 5, 5);

            //Here is the Zoom function I Want.
            Zoom(rects,zoomData);

            //Increase and decrease zoom.
            if(zoomData.level<=0.5){
                zoomData.direction = 1;
            } else if(zoomData.level>=1.5){
                zoomData.direction = -1;
            }
            zoomData.level+=0.01*zoomData.direction;

            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }

        //The zoom function I want.
        function Zoom(rects,zoom){
            for(var rect of rects){
                /* Update the rectangles data (x, y, w, h) based on the zoom level and zoom point.
                rect.x = ...
                rect.y = ...
                */
                //I Think the size is the easy part:
                rect.w = rect.originalW * zoom.level;
                rect.h = rect.originalH * zoom.level;
            }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Canvas Zoom Rectangles</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You want your images to zoom relatively to the white point? Or in a way their center stays in the same place?

Comment: The first one you said. Relatively to the white point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it myself.

This is the new position of the rectangles:

```
rect.x = rect.originalX * zoom.level + zoom.x * (1 - zoom.level);
rect.y = rect.originalY * zoom.level + zoom.y * (1 - zoom.level);
```

Here is the final sample code:

```js
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const canvasW = canvas.width;
        const canvasH = canvas.height;

        //These will be images, but the idea is the same.
        var rects = [
            {
                originalX:10,
                x:10,
                originalY:10,
                y:10,
                originalW:25,
                w:25,
                originalH:25,
                h:25,
                color:'blue'
            },
            {
                originalX:90,
                x:90,
                originalY:40,
                y:40,
                originalW:65,
                w:65,
                originalH:35,
                h:35,
                color:'red'
            },
            {
                originalX:80,
                x:80,
                originalY:120,
                y:120,
                originalW:30,
                w:30,
                originalH:30,
                h:30,
                color:'pink'
            },
            {
                originalX:180,
                x:180,
                originalY:190,
                y:190,
                originalW:45,
                w:45,
                originalH:35,
                h:35,
                color:'green'
            }
        ];


        //Zoom Data:
        var zoomData = {
            x:150, //The center of the zoom function. (The canvas center in this case)
            y:150, // <-->
            level: 1, //Zoom level: 1 means no change, >1 means zoom content, <1 means unzoom content.
            direction: 1 //Zoom direction: 1 means increasing, -1 decreasing.
        };



        function draw(){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);

            //Draw some background.
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);

            //Draw each rectangle (image).
            for(var rect of rects){
                ctx.fillStyle = rect.color;
                ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
            }

            //Draw the zoom center point.
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            ctx.fillRect(zoomData.x - 5/2, zoomData.y - 5/2, 5, 5);

            //Here is the Zoom function I Want.
            Zoom(rects,zoomData);

            //Increase and decrease zoom.
            if(zoomData.level<=0.5){
                zoomData.direction = 1;
            } else if(zoomData.level>=1.5){
                zoomData.direction = -1;
            }
            zoomData.level+=0.01*zoomData.direction;

            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }

        //The zoom function I want.
        function Zoom(rects,zoom){
            for(var rect of rects){
                /* Update the rectangles data (x, y, w, h) based on the zoom level and zoom point. */
                rect.w = rect.originalW * zoom.level;
                rect.h = rect.originalH * zoom.level;
                rect.x = rect.originalX * zoom.level + zoom.x * (1 - zoom.level);
                rect.y = rect.originalY * zoom.level + zoom.y * (1 - zoom.level);
            }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Canvas Elements zoom</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```